# Completely remove firefox snap package

Tags: package-management, firefox, snap, snap-store

In Ubuntu 22.04 the firefox snap was installed as default. I just removed it using the command `sudo snap remove firefox` but inside the file computer/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps there exists an firefox snap locked package weighing about 163 mb how can I remove that

[image: the package with it's location]

Comment: This worked like a charm. Hope it helps you like it helped me. https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/amp/

Answer (score 54):

For those who get the error in Ubuntu 22.04:

```
$ sudo snap remove --purge firefox
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "firefox" (1943) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_ZA.dic: read-only file system)
```

Verify that indeed `/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell` is mounted as an ext4 file system using `lsblk -fe7 -o+ro`

If so, stop the Firefox service

```
$ sudo systemctl stop var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount
$ sudo systemctl disable var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount 
Removed /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount.
```

Then the uninstall command should work:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a life saver!

Comment: @Mooncake I'm glad to hear that my "journey" is saving valuable time for others, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: thanks a lot you saved the day.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked flawlessly!

Comment: thank this work!

Comment: That worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL WITH `--purge`! IT WILL DELETE BOTH THE PROFILE IN YOUR SNAP FOLDER AND ITS BACKUP.

Answer (score 11):

You used `sudo snap remove firefox` but you should have used

- `snap disable firefox`
- `snap remove --purge firefox`

[reference](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/)

Comment: So do I need to install firefox once again using that snap package installing it via software installer then using the above commands

Comment: Once removed, you can install the APT version if you prefer (or re-install the snap). The instructions to install the APT version are in the reference link provided in my answer.

Comment: Ok, since I purged the firefox I cannot install that package again from seed directory using software installer, so if I install it from software centre an snap version can I completely remove the seed file by using above command.

Comment: I followed the instructions in my answer and `Firefox` is still available in `Ubuntu Software` as a snap so your comment seems not to make sense 

Comment: No, I meant installing the firefox for the above package again which I shown in the image in the original question, so if I install firefox snap again from the Ubuntu software centre again and in terminal if I execute the command ```sudo snap disable firefox && snap remove --purge firefox``` will I be able to remove the firefox fully even from seed library

Comment: I really don't understand your question about the seed library. To state again; I performed the command as written and Firefox is still available as a snap should I wish to download it as such. 

Comment: snap remove --purge firefox gave me an error:
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "firefox" (1918) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.dic: read-only file system)

Answer (score 7):

The following commands can be used to remove Firefox snap:

```bash
sudo umount /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Comment: Minor typo - `umount`.

Comment: Thank you. This was the correct solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

Files in that folder (`/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps`) came pre-installed with the operating system. No `snap` command will remove them. Deleting them manually will remove them, but can potentially break something eventually maybe. If you won't be using the firefox snap, most likely it's fine to just manually delete the file, but there is always the potential that it may break something later.

If you want to install Firefox as a .deb, you can follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/1083397) to install the Mozilla PPA and prevent `apt` from "updating" to a `snap` automatically.