# Unable to delete the snap version of Firefox from Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: firefox, snap, snap-store

I am deleting all snap apps using the command `sudo snap remove --purge "app name"` with the end goal of completely removing the snap store. I have been able to remove all apps other than Firefox. I am getting the following error when trying to remove Firefox.

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "firefox" (2015) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_GB.dic: read-only file system).
```

Would appreciate some guidance

Comment: I know a few have posted questions here about how after removing snapd they no longer had a working OS. I would not be touching it.

Comment: I do not have a valid reason other than being really new to ubuntu and reading that snaps are slow and there are better alternatives, however I appreciate the advice and will reconsider my decision.

Comment: If you want to remove Firefox this is the command you should have used.  sudo snap remove firefox

Comment: I tried sudo snap remove firefox and getting the same error as before, which is why I tried sudo snap remove --purge firefox.

Comment: Did you try [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434769/590937)?

Comment: linked posted by @mook765 worked for me.

Comment: "*snaps are slow and there are better alternatives*" is generally FUD. Some folks who dislike any random thing can be loud and sometimes get outsized attention. Research and the opinions of others can only take you so far. Advice: Try it yourself before judging it or removing it. It's part of Ubuntu for some very good reasons.