# Cannot uninstall Firefox snap

Tags: package-management, firefox, snap, 22.10

I’m trying to remove the snap “firefox” on Ubuntu 22.10. Unfortunately, an error prevents the task from being completed.

```
# snap list

Nome               Versione          Rev    Tracciamento     Publisher   Note

bare               1.0               5      latest/stable    canonical?  base
core               16-2.58.2         14784  latest/stable    canonical?  core
core18             20230207          2697   latest/stable    canonical?  base
core20             20230126          1822   latest/stable    canonical?  base
firefox            106.0-1           1969   latest/stable/?  mozilla?    -
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.6f39565     119    latest/stable    canonical?  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-81-g442e511   1535   latest/stable    canonical?  -
hello-world        6.4               29     latest/stable    canonical?  -
snap-store         41.3-66-gfe1e325  638    latest/stable    canonical?  -
snapd              2.58.2            18357  latest/stable    canonical?  snapd
```

when I invoke Firefox, it starts correctly. At this point, I tried to remove the snap firefox like this :

```
$ snap remove --purge firefox
```

but it does not want to do it :

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap 'firefox' (1969) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.aff: read-only file system)
```

I've found this [helpful question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414173/completely-remove-firefox-snap-package) and so,this is what I did :

```
root@marietto-BHYVE:/etc/systemd/system# lsblk -fe7 -o+ro

NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                                         FSAVAIL FSUSE%   MOUNTPOINTS                     RO

vda                                                                                                                                                                                                   0
--vda1
        vfat             FAT32              A17A-EEFA                                                504,9M     1%   /boot/efi                                             0
--vda2
        ext4            1.0                   2e254150-7969-4cbb-bf4c-9b9e0bf9ef64  160,8G    13%  /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                                                                                  /                                                         0

# sudo systemctl stop var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount

Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
root@marietto-BHYVE:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl daemon-reload


root@marietto-BHYVE:/etc/systemd/system# lsblk -fe7 -o+ro

NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                                         FSAVAIL FSUSE%   MOUNTPOINTS                     RO

vda                                                                                                                                                                                                   0
--vda1
        vfat             FAT32              A17A-EEFA                                                504,9M     1%   /boot/efi                                             0
--vda2
        ext4            1.0                   2e254150-7969-4cbb-bf4c-9b9e0bf9ef64  160,8G    13%  /                                                         0  


root@marietto-BHYVE:/etc/systemd/system# snap remove firefox

2023-02-24T14:06:57+01:00 ERROR cannot remove snap file "firefox", will retry in 3 mins: unlinkat /snap/firefox/1969/data-dir: read-only file system.
```

Comment: If you remove `snapd` automatically most the snaps are removed (AFAIK). The system snaps are the leftovers.(Not recommended to remove snapd)

Comment: Usually I'm able to clean everything,this time I went inside a black hole. snap has the worst mechanism ever created until linux is born (my opinion). I hate it and I'm not alone.

Comment: `snapd` is a new technology, so it's lacking in a lot of features and drivers(even I hate it).  I can't help you further as I'm relatively new to snaps.

Comment: Same issue here and removing snapd left my system in the same mess, no solution found yet.