# firefox 119.0 that came with 22.04 won't open files in /tmp

Tags: firefox, tmp

The firefox 119.0 that came with 22.04 won't open files in /tmp

```
file:///tmp/foo.html

Problem loading page

File not found

Firefox can’t find the file at /tmp/foo.html.
```

but it ***is*** there!
`% ls -l /tmp/foo.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ian ian 27631 Oct 31 14:10 /tmp/foo.html`

If I move the file anywhere else then ff can read it:

`% mv /tmp/foo.html ~
% cd
% ls -l foo.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ian ian 27631 Oct 31 14:10 foo.html`

`file:///home/ian/foo.html` loads just fine.  ff just refuses to load anything from /tmp!  Why??

Comment: The Firefox snap is sandboxed. The sandbox prohibits reading files outside of ~ and /var/www.

Comment: I installed the firefox package and got everything working (no more sandbox), but after a few days firefox updated itself in the background and when I restarted I was back to the snap version.  How can I keep this from happening again?

Comment: That seems like a completely different question (that has already been asked). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414173/completely-remove-firefox-snap-package