# Installing Firefox dev edition

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to install Firefox Browser Developer Edition (.tar.bz2 file).
I've followed a guide and it works, just doesn't seem to operate as a browser (or an app), it doesn't have a logo (default cog thingy) I can't favorite it in the task bar and it doesn't come up in the list when trying to choose a default browser either. would love some help fixing it or reinstalling it in a different way, thanks!

Comment: What version is Firefox Browser Developer Edition and Ubuntu? Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1493916/edit) your question and add these details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Firefox tarball from from Mozilla website as a regular app, then you will have to [create a .desktop file](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/) with the following contents, and save it in `/home/your-username/.local/share/applications`, with the filename `firefox-beta.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=/path/to/firefox-beta-binary %u
Icon=firefox
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;application/x-xpinstall;application/pdf;application/json;
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;profile-manager-window;
StartupWMClass=firefox

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/path/to/firefox-beta-binary --new-window %u

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=/path/to/firefox-beta-binary --private-window %u
```

You will have to replace `/path/to/firefox-beta-binary` with the actual path where you saved the developer edition.

---

You can also use the official Firefox Beta PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

Then, copy and paste the following code in a terminal in one go (don't copy-paste line by line) to prioritize the beta version of firefox over the snap version.

```
echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: firefox
Pin: version 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: -1
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

Next, remove the snap version of firefox

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

If you see this error,

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "firefox" (1943) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_ZA.dic: read-only file system)
```

Then run the following commands ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434769/124466)) to disable the hunspell service, and try removing Firefox snap once again.

```
sudo systemctl stop var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount
sudo systemctl disable var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Install Firefox the beta version of Firefox from the PPA.

```
sudo apt install firefox
```