My Firefox is not launching in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I upgraded recently my OS to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
My previous Firefox which was working great under Ubuntu 20.04 stopped launching. I downloaded a new Firefox (Firefox-126.0) and got it install and still same problem.
Is Firefox is not supported any more by Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS?
How I can fix this problem and be able to use Firefox again?

Please start FF from command line and watch what is thrown. It is likely a broken profile. Profiles do not get overwritten with a new FF ;)

In 22.04 Firefox is snap package.

Try replacing snap firefox with the traditional deb package https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. Please [edit] your Question to explain "sropped launching".

Thank you all for your assistant.. I tried this method mentioned by "Archisman Panigrahi"  and it worked like a charm.

Does this answer your question? How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?

These are the steps I followed and found in the link mentioned by Archisman Panigrahi How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?
To remove the Snap Firefox version ( which is stopping Firefox from launching )
Do the commands starting by the sign ( -> )
-> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
-> echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
Package: firefox
Pin: version 1:1snap*
Pin-Priority: -1
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
-> sudo snap remove firefox
....
If you see the following error below:
error:
cannot perform the following tasks:

Remove data for snap "firefox" (1943) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_ZA.dic: read-only file system)

..
==>> Then do the following command to Verify that indeed
(   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell      ), is mounted as an "ext4" file system using the command below:

-> lsblk -fe7 -o+ro
....
-> sudo systemctl stop var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
-> sudo systemctl disable var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
Then the uninstall command to remove finally the snap version of Firefox:
-> sudo snap remove firefox
Followd by the "APT"'s command below to install Firefox:
-> sudo apt install firefox
....
Note:
If in the future Firefox sends a new update and the problem starts again then repeat the whole procedure all over again

References/sources, were got from :
How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?
Sources
https://askubuntu.com/a/1434769/124466
Completely remove firefox snap package

Mozilla puts out a new version of Firefox about every 6 weeks.

If it was installed as a snap remove it as a snap no need for this massive set of steps.
